# Add value to the labels on chartnewjs legend

Tags: chart.js

i want to add the value for each label on pie chart legend and not just the label itself. on chart.js there was an option to add legend template but it seems to not working on newchart.js

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and played with some time with overriding the "legendTemplate" option. I seems that the default legendTemplate uses the invalid variable "datasets" which should be now "segments".

So the solution could look like the following:

1. copy default value for legendTemplate
2. replace all "datasets" with "segments"
3. add "<%=segments[i].value%>" to the end

Example:

```
  myNewChart = new Chart(chartContext).Pie(data, {
            legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%>  <%=segments[i].value%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
        });
```

Sadly, I couldn't fix the css for the legend so the color coding etc. won't display.

Comment: segments seems to be valid only for pie charts. Maybe you can provide more information about your chart type, the chart.js version and what exactly doesn't work